# How can I do C style casting in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, ctype, directcast

I have a object type variable (control .Tag) that I need to cast to a structured type, and change a member in. This is a contrived but representative example:

```
Public Structure struct_COLOURS
  Dim ILikeRed as boolean
  Dim ILikeGreen as boolean
End Structure

Dim AnObject as Object = (some source that is struct_COLOURS)

DirectCast(AnObject, struct_COLOURS).ILikeRed = True ' This is not valid syntax?!
```

I don't remember my C syntax very well, but it would be something like this:

```
(struct_COLOURS*)AnObject->ILikeRed = true;
```

The point is I can cast an object to something and set members in the resulting cast. It seems as though DirectCast is actually a function and is not casting in the way I would interpret it.

Oddly, if you only want to retrieve a member value, you can use DirectCast:

```
dim YummyRed AS Boolean = DirectCast(AnObject, struct_COLOURS).ILikeRed
```

is just fine!

If I cannot cast the way I want, and I cannot change the use of the Tag property (so please don't suggest, it's not an option) to store these structures, what is the fastest way to set members?

Answer (score 7):

> It seems as though DirectCast is actually a function and is not casting in the way I would interpret it.

No, that’s wrong: `DirectCast` isn’t a method, it’s a real language construct, like a cast in C.

*However*, if you store a structure (= value type) in an object, it gets [**boxed**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) and, by consequence, *copied*. This is causing the problem here: you’re attempting to modify a copy, not the original, boxed object.

So in order to change a member of a boxed value type object, you need to copy the object, change its value, and copy it back:

```
Dim tmp = DirectCast(AnObject, struct_COLOURS)
tmp.ILikeRed = True
AnObject = tmp
```

Incidentally, the same is true in C#, despite the superficial similarity to the C cast syntax.

Comment: How do I put something in there that isn't boxed but is structured?

Comment: OK. How about I store all my structs in a seperate typed array and the Tag just contains the index? The relationship would be consistent for the life time of the controls. I would need to change a lot of code but moving the data out of the tag object is a longer term objective anyway, just not one I wanted to tackle now.

Comment: @Mark Value types are *always* boxed when stored in an `Object`, there’s no way around that. Storing the index to a global array might be an acceptable solution in your case.

Comment: My last comment went awol. Why don't I just derive my own controls and make the structure a property or lots of properties. Means a ton of changes I wanted to avoid, but it would mean no object types to worry about everytime I wanted to query the structure.

Comment: @Mark That could be the cleanest solution but it might be overkill.

Answer (score -2):

That's how you should cast - with CType:

```
Dim myColor As Object = Nothing
        Dim color As Color = CType(myColor, Color)
        color.Name = "red"
```

Why a struct and not a class?

Comment: No, that’s wrong. First of all, that’s unrelated to the problem. Secondly, `CType` is not preferred here. In fact, `DirectCast` should always be preferred because it’s more restrictive and allows better type checking. Thirdly, your code doesn’t follow good style by declaring `myColor` without initialising it straightaway.

Comment: A class is overkill if all you want to do is store a collection of variables in an organised fashion. A structure is, or should be, extremely efficient because it just a lump of memory being read in a certain way. Besides, wouldn't a class have to be cast in the same way?